# Suspended from reviewing

Tags: support, review-queues, review-suspension

I've just started doing some reviews. One of the answers was not a proper one, more like an edit to the question. It already had a comment pointing this out, so I just upvoted the comment (it automatically selected the other action option) and moved on the next one.

Now I've received a ban on reviewing (for 2 days) because of this, saying I should have marked the answer as not an answer. Now, I'd like to check back on the answer, to see what I've actually done, because upvoting the comment doesn't seem suspension worthy to me, but the answer is already removed, so I can't check the history.

Any suggestions on how to see what my actions were? And did upvoting a comment really count as approving the answer?

[image: screenshot of the suspension message]

[image: screenshot of the review that lead to the suspension]

I can add any of the links from the pictures, I just wasn't sure which one were made for me, and would be visible to others too.

Comment: You don't get a suspension from one bad review. It's according to a pattern. And also the review you posted here is not even an audit so I doubt you can get suspended because of it...

Comment: You reviewed an answer that clearly wasn't an answer, decided to not flag it as NAA, instead take an action that technically completes the review and removes the post from the review queue so no other reviewer can take the appropriate action and still are surprised you were suspended from reviewing? Upvoting that comment doesn't do anything useful and you can't know if it was already flagged.

Comment: @Tomerikoo the log says it was due to this one. If I've made more bad choices, I'd certainly like to know what they were, so I would avoid them in the future.

Comment: It can have been a manual suspension, too.

Comment: I might be wrong, but anyway it's hard to have any doubts. The message you posted is quite clear: *"Although the post reviewed was posted as an answer, it did not attempt to provide an answer to the question. __You should have flagged it as Not an answer__"*

Comment: It's due to that answer. It was a manual ban imposed by a moderator. @Jeanne's comment says it as well as I could, so I won't bother trying. The point of reviewing is to *resolve the problems*, not to complete the review tasks. Just because the system accepted upvoting the comment as sufficient doesn't mean that it actually was sufficient. Upvoting a comment doesn't remove the inappropriate answers from the site. Next time, flag as NAA. There's no harm in multiple users doing so; you don't have to worry about whether a commenter also did so. And, now you know, so you won't get suspended again.

Comment: Lesson learned. Wished I knew before to mark wrong answers (unhelpful, not an answers, etc) as such is the requirement, not just to do something else (like upvoting the comment). As you said, yes, won't make the mistake again. Thanks guys

Comment: Cool. Since you know that now, I'm lifting your review suspension. The whole point of the suspension was to let you know how to change your behavior, and since it's already had that effect, there's no reason for you to still be suspended.

Comment: Thanks, but I'll still take a break for a moment, to let it sit for a while. Have a good day

Comment: Also, while a review suspension may seem like a huge escalation or heavy-handed measure in this case, a short review suspension is actually a valid, staff-approved tool for mods to use to point users' attention to a single bad review.

Comment: oh no, while I may have been unhappy with it when it arrived, it served it's purpose, and got me to realize, that I wasn't reviewing the answer, rather the comment, which was useless.

Comment: Another thing that many reviewers may not realize -- if you're unsure of how to review a question or an answer, you may (and *should*) skip it.

Comment: nobody said skipping is better than anything else. Skipping is better if you are unsure of what action to perform. But if you know the answer is proper, you should approve it.